# CLJSRN Release Build Runtime Failure

Tags: android, react-native, clojurescript

I inherited this CLJS React Native codebase and I'm trying to upgrade the Android SDK to v26 with React 16.4 and RN 0.56. The debug build works great but the release build fails when starting up with the following call stack:

```
2018-11-21 10:31:30.731 16727-16790/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
Process: XXX, PID: 16727
com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Can't find variable: a, stack:
<unknown>@12:60553
<unknown>@12:60366
<unknown>@12:518500
c@2:822
i@2:394
t@2:324
global code@322:8
    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.showOrThrowError(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:54)
    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportFatalException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:38)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:160)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:192)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Any ideas on how to get the non-minified version of the call stack? Is the minification done by the cljs to js compiler? Or the RN bundler/packager?

I'm currently using advanced optimizations on the cljs to js compiler. If I switch it to whitespace optimizations, then I get a build error

```
transform[stderr]: FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

I can work around it by doing the bundling separately

```
node --expose-gc --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js bundle --verbose --platform android --dev true --reset-cache --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output /usr/src/app/android/app/build/intermediates/assets/release/index.android.bundle --assets-dest /usr/src/app/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release
```

But I hit another failure

```
Unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle'.
```

Any ideas what else I can try?

Update 1: The "Unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle'." error message was caused by the index.android.bundle file being placed in the wrong folder. The following command worked:

```
node --expose-gc --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js bundle --verbose --platform android --dev true --reset-cache --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output /usr/src/app/android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest /usr/src/app/android/app/src/main/res/
```

The unminified call stack looks like:

```
2018-11-27 15:07:00.740 23765-23859/? E/ReactNativeJNI: Got JS Exception: Can't find variable: document (index.android.bundle:1632)
2018-11-27 15:07:00.740 23765-23859/? E/ReactNativeJNI: Got JS Stack: index.android.bundle:1632:43
loadModuleImplementation@index.android.bundle:162:14
guardedLoadModule@index.android.bundle:83:47
metroRequire@index.android.bundle:72:79
global code@index.android.bundle:1639:8
2018-11-27 15:07:00.749 23765-23859/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_js
Process: XXX, PID: 23765
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.facebook.react.devsupport.JSException: Can't find variable: document (index.android.bundle:1632)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.DefaultNativeModuleCallExceptionHandler.handleException(DefaultNativeModuleCallExceptionHandler.java:22)
    at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DisabledDevSupportManager.handleException(DisabledDevSupportManager.java:170)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.onNativeException(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:525)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.access$1000(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:39)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl$NativeExceptionHandler.handleException(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:541)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:192)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: com.facebook.react.devsupport.JSException: Can't find variable: document (index.android.bundle:1632)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:192) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
 Caused by: com.facebook.jni.CppException: Can't find variable: document (index.android.bundle:1632)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:192) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APK worked OK after I restarted the RN upgrade process with react-native-git-upgrade. There was another issue after the upgrade with some unresolved symbol during runtime but that turned out to be an issue with the externs file because I had switched from the deprecated BackAndroid to BackHandler.